# Cannot find default value for object, in JavaScript HTTP adapter issue in IBM worklight 8.0

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I am using Javascript HTTP adapter, one of the procedure is not working always its throwing Cannot find default value for an object error, could you please check the below piece of procedure call as well as used object and help me where I did mistake.

```
Procedure call:

function details(tag) {
var path = PATH+'upload/save';
var input = {
    method : 'POST',
    returnedContentType : 'application/json',
    path : path,
    body : {
        contentType : "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        content : tag
    }
};
return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

}

```
Used Object:
[{"rId":"5957","tId":"1234","imno":"","dirName":"/storage/emulated/0/demo/Data/1234","userId":"guest","count":"5"}]

Response: always 500 and    "successful": false,
```

Could you please help me why I am getting always can not find default value for object error.

Comment: By "used object" do you mean, this the data that was sent to the adapter from the client? Also, I assume 'PATH' has a proper value ?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace or log snippet of the actual error.

Comment: This does not help. Please open a case with IBM MFP support for detailed analysis

Comment: I found issue, and fixed, now it is working.

Comment: Can you please add the fix you found, as the answer to the query? That will help someone else facing the same issue.